# Use touchscreen as touchpad?

Tags: touchscreen

I bought a Acer Iconia Tab w500 awhile back and all in all I love it. One thing tablets kinda ruin is gaming, especially games not intended for touchscreen devices that don't have a traditional mouse. One game I'm completely hooked on but can't play is Minecraft. It uses the usual mechanic of moving the pointer to the center of the window and when the user moves the pointer with a traditional mouse, it measures the offset and places the mouse back at the center. On touchscreens, this is next to impossible to work with.

What I'm hoping for as a possible fix is a way of toggling the touchscreen behavior from 1:1 point and click to more of a touch pad like behavior, meaning once I place my finger down, the mouse moves relative to how I move my finger around the initial touch down. Does Windows have a setting to toggle this behavior? Is there a 3rd party application to achieve this?

Comment: I know there are applications which can help do this, but I don't know if you would be able to use then with a full-screen 3D application.

Comment: Minecraft does not have to be run full screen.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for Windows 8:

[TouchMousePointer](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchmousepointer/en-us/) - its a virtual on-screen touchpad.

You can use it on the side, or transparent floating or fullscreen.

On windowed games it works floating or on the side, but for fullscreen games it only works correctly with fullscreen mode, then the whole screen simulates a touchpad, meaning that the mouse doesn't go where you tap, but it can be moved by taping and moving anywhere on the screen like on a touchpad.

And a two finger tap results in a right-click.

Perfect workaround for old games!

Comment: At the time this was asked (3 years ago) it had to work on Windows 7.

Comment: So what do you think? This seems to work fine on Windows 8